# SQL limit inserted/updated data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 1 table in which I store values. Let's call them "Gems".

I made a button that adds/updates table +10 "Gems" on `submit`.

I don't know if there is any way to limit the inserted data without using javascript. For example my goal is to limit 100 gems per day. Or limit max number of clicks per day. Any suggestions on how to make that?

I tried:

```
UPDATE backpack SET gems = gems + 10 WHERE member = '$user_id'";
```

Comment: You definitely shouldn't do it on the client side or people will find ways around your restrictions and give themselves "gems"

Comment: I dont have any transactions in mind,just virtual curency to be used as limit for downloads.

Comment: I agree with the first comment. You're going to have to do this on the server, and you're going to need to keep track of each click with the user_id and date. When a user clicks you check the count for that date (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clicks WHERE member = '$user_id' AND date > todayAtMidnight`). If the count < 10 then you can add a new entry to the clicks table and update the backpack table like you were originally planning.

Comment: You can do the SELECT as part of the INSERT

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one mySQL query. Suppose you want to add 10 gems for a limit of 100 gems daily. Here is my try:

```
CREATE TABLE `Gems` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gems` int(11),
  `gCount` varchar(45),
  `gDate` date,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ;

INSERT INTO `Gems` VALUES 
(1,220,'100','2016-04-09'),
(2,310,'50','2016-04-09'),
(3,110,'20','2016-04-08');

| user_id | gems | gCount |      gDate |
|---------|------|--------|------------|
|       1 |  220 |    100 | 2016-04-09 |
|       2 |  320 |     60 | 2016-04-09 |
|       3 |  110 |     20 | 2016-04-08 |
```

So the logic you need is:

```
if gDate >= CURDATE and gCount < 100 and gCount+10 <= 100
{
    gems = gems + 10;
    gCount = gCount + 10;
}
else if gDate < CURDATE
{
    gDate = CURDATE;
    gCount = 10;
    gems = gems + 10;
}
```

and the equivalent mySQL Update statement which will do the job:

```
UPDATE Gems 
SET 
    gems = IF((gDate >= CURDATE() AND gCount < 100 AND gCount+10 <= 100)
            OR gDate < CURDATE(),
        gems + 10,
        gems),
    gCount = IF((gDate >= CURDATE() AND gCount < 100 AND gCount+10 <= 100),
        gCount + 10,
        IF(gDate < CURDATE(), 10, gCount)),
    gDate = IF(gDate < CURDATE(), CURDATE(), gDate)
WHERE
    user_id = <user_id>;
```